# C++: When do I need to think about possible memory leaks?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

Can I, with my own code, in C++ accidentally produce memory leaks without taking use of `new` and the `malloc` function? (and all other stdlib functions that allocate memory)

Comment: If you stay with C++ code and good libraries then it is unlikely you will leak **if you don't use new** (as good libraries should return objects not pointers). If you use C libraries then you need to be a lot more careful as any pointer returned to you may (or may not) need to be managed.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't allocate anything on the heap then in general you won't have to worry about memory leaks.

If you don't call functions that allocate stuff on the heap, then all your data is held on the stack and will be destroyed when it is popped.

Comment: Downvoted. Consider this code: vector<int> v; while(1) v.push_back(1); You don't have any "heap" allocation functions, and yet you get a memory leak eventually.

Comment: @Dragontamer5788 Upvoted. But the memory can still *be* released (e.g. it's not a pointer that is forgotten about) -- we aren't trying to solve the halting problem here. (The answer also uses appropriately tempered language.)

Comment: I find that definition... not very useful (even if it is the wikipedia definition). I figure, any permanent increase in memory consumption that can threaten the lifespan of a long-running process to be a "memory leak". Unfortunately... because our definitions contradict each other, it is unlikely that we'll find a resolution. So I'll keep the down vote and end the debate here.

Comment: @Dragontamer5788 - sorry, if the program still has control of the memory, it's not leaked in the classic sense. Yes, it's a bug, but it's not the sort of bug we talk about as being a memory leak. Memory leaks are (classically) when the program has completely forgotten about the memory and couldn't free it if it wanted to.

Comment: @Dragontamer5788 - how is that a memory leak?  A memory leak, by definition, occurs when an allocated block of memory becomes no longer *reachable* by the program.  In your infinite loop example, there is never a time when the allocated memory becomes unreachable.  So no memory is actually leaking.  You can argue about differing "definitions", but I think this is settled pretty definitively by the fact that actual memory leak detection tools, like Valgrind, would certainly NOT report any memory leaks when executing your example code.

Comment: @Charles and @Michael: Using "Memory Leak" in this respect is common useage. See this article for instance: http://olex.openlogic.com/wazi/2009/how-to-fix-memory-leaks-in-java/ . This is the textbook "Memory Leak in Java", and any search on "Memory Leak Java" will come up with a variant of this example. As I stated before, our definitions of "Memory leak" differ. Perhaps it is my Java background. And because our definitions differ, there is no hope for this argument.

Comment: @Michael and @Charles: In advance, sorry to reopen the "debate". But I dislike the wording of your arguments. So... debate time it is :-)

Comment: @Dragontamer5788 Your code contains a first order defect.  It hangs pegging the CPU on that thread.  Most commonly, the symptom first observed would be the hang/CPU consumption.  In solving the hang, the "leak", as defined by you, no longer exists.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use `malloc` in C++.

You need to worry about memory management whenever you attempt to manually manage dynamic (allocated using `new`) memory, whether you allocated it yourself, or you obtained it calling some function. (A function's documentation should tell you whether you need to free whatever it returns and which method to do so you need to use.)
What's more, you need to worry about ***every resource*** you acquire, be this memory, open files, locked mutexes, or whatever. You do *not* need to worry when you're employing techniques like [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

Many resources (strings, array, and other containers, files, etc.) already come wrapped in RAII classes. Use them and worry more about your algorithms, and less about resource management details.

Answer (score 1):

- `_strdup` in CRT creates a buffer that should be deleted with `free`.
- There are some Windows SDK functions that could create buffers that you should delete. `FormatMessage` may create a buffer that should be deleted with `LocalFree`.
- If you catch [structured exceptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft-specific_exception_handling_mechanisms) and prevent the stack from unwinding then memory may leak.
- If you start a thread and don't let it finish properly before the main thread finishes then there will be memory leak (at the end of the application life, but it's still a leak).

Answer (score 0):

Memory **on the heap** gets only allocated with such function/operator (or other non-functions).

Of course if you're using some non-standard function, it could allocate memory in the heap. If they aren't bugged they should take care about deleting their stuff, or explicitly state in the documentation that function caller will take ownership of allocated data.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard without allocating heap memory (which is what malloc and new do), but not impossible.  Let's say you were developing a game.

```
void playGame()
{
    ...
    showResults();
}

void showResults()
{
    ...
    if (playAgain)
        playGame();
    else
        exit(0);
}
```

In this example, the stack keeps growing as long as the user keeps choosing to play again.  If the user chooses to play again, the playGame function is called, but since showResults hasn't returned, the original playGame also hasn't returned, so all the stack variables created there are still around. The new playGame instance creates new copies of those variables.  If the player keeps playing again and again, you could run out of stack space.  This might not technically be called a memory leak, but it's similar.  Memory you are done using isn't being freed.

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't that be a stack overflow rather than a memory leak then?

Comment: A stack overflow is a different far more dangerous bug and security problem. What happens here is the OS will keep giving the stack more and more space, and eventually, your process will run out of memory. A Stack Overflow may result in remote code execution. Something like this will just close your process.

Comment: I don't consider a memory leak to be something exclusive to the heap.  Wikipedia defines a memory leak to be "when a computer program consumes memory but is unable to release it back to the operating system."

Comment: What is the above then, if not a stack overflow? It's a recursive function call that goes deeper and deeper with time, and once it runs out of memory it will cause one.

Comment: I stand corrected. I was confused with a buffer overflow. Either way, a stack overflow is a memory leak.

Comment: It's not a memory leak. Allocated data doesn't get lost. When playGame() eventually returns, all previous data (allocated on the stack) will get freed.

Comment: Its not a memory leak: all processes return their memory to the operating system when the process exits. </sarcasm>. I don't like turning "memory leak" problems into "halting theorem" problems.

Comment: In Java, there are situations where a reference to an object remains, even though it will never be used again. That data isn't "lost", but the garbage collector will never free it.  I've seen that listed as a type of memory leak before.

Answer (score 0):

No. If you don't allocate memory, you can't leak it.

Typically if you need memory allocation using 'new' or 'malloc', RAII suggests that classes take explicit ownership that memory and clean it up in the destructor.

```
class blah {
  public:
    blah(): thing(null) { thing = new thing(); }
    ~blah() { delete thing; }
  private:
    thing *thing;
};
```

If you really need dynamic memory allocation (not explicitly owned) use a unique_ptr.

```
void func() {
  std::unique_ptr<W> because(new thing);
  because->because();
}
```